# One of the difference between JSP include directive and JSP include tag

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Accodign to the JSP specification:

> A JSP container can include a mechanism for being notified if an
>   included file changes, so the container can recompile the JSP page.
>   However, the JSP 1.2 specification does not have a way of directing
>   the JSP container that included files have changed.

And I found this in an on-line tutorial:

> If the included file is changed but not the JSP which is including it
>   then the changes will reflect only when we use include action tag. The
>   changes will not reflect if you are using include directive as the JSP
>   is not changed so it will not be translated (during this phase only
>   the  file gets included when using directive) for request processing
>   and hence the changes will not reflect.

then, I write an example to try it : A.jsp, B.jsp, and C.jsp,

A.jsp includes C.jsp using JSP include directive：

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/C.jsp" %>
```

B.jsp includes C.jsp using JSP include tag:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/C.jsp" />
```

and when I access A.jsp and B.jsp in the borwser, thay both display normally, 
then I changed C.jsp, and I refeshed A.jsp and B.jsp, both of them can display the change of C.jsp. but if the JSP spec is true, the A.jsp shouldn't display the change of C.jsp.
is there anything wrong?

Comment: That initial quote is not taken from the JSP specification. It appears to be taken from an online tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we shall take this,

`<%@ include file="/jsp/C.jsp" %>`

1. include directive will paste the page as it is in the place where
   this statement is used.
2. If you have made changes in your static content either its in `A.jsp` or `C.jsp`, it will be rendered with the changes that you made.

`<jsp:include page="/jsp/C.jsp" />`

1. This include action tag is used to insert either a static or dynamic
   content.
2. So the changes will reflect as it is i.e the `C.jsp` will
   executed by passing the request and response objects to it and
   include the executed page in the `A.jsp`.

EDIT :

For example,

In `B.jsp`,

```
<c:out value="${value}"/>
```

In `A.jsp`,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="value" value="10"/>

<span>From @include <%@include file="B.jsp" %></span>
<span>From jsp:include <jsp:include page="B.jsp" /></span>
```

When the page is loaded it will be,

```
From @include 10
From jsp:include
```

if you inspect and see, it will look like,

```
<span>From @include 10</span>
<span>From jsp:include <c:out value/></span>
```

This is because, `@include` will replace the contents of `B.jsp` into `A.jsp` before the rendering starts, where as for `jsp:include` , `A.jsp` and `B.jsp` will execute separately.

As the `taglib` is not imported in `B.jsp`, the `c:out` tag is not executed.

Upon changing `B.jsp` to

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:out value="${value}"/>
```

if you inspect and see the rendered page, it will look like,

```
<span>From @include 10</span>
<span>From jsp:include </span>
```

variable `value` has its scope only in `A.jsp`.

In `jsp:include`

> scope is page

In `@include`

> scope is request

Comment: could you five me a code example of "Where as if you have scriptlets in both A.jsp and C.jsp and if you change in C.jsp, it wont be reflected as the source jsp (A.jsp) is not changed."? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The actual text on this topic from the JSP specification is:

> A JSP container can include a mechanism for being notified if an included file changes, so the container can recompile the JSP page. However, the JSP 1.2 specification does not have a way of directing the JSP container that included files have changed.

The same text appears unaltered (apart from the specification version) in all subsequent versions of the specification to the current one (2.3 at the time of writing).

Most JSP containers will detect the change in the included file and trigger a re-compilation when the including file is next requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/C.jsp" %>
```

do insert content dynamically,
suppose you include `C.jsp` in you `A.jsp`, so if you have declared variable in `C.jsp` you can refer it in you `A.jsp` at compile and run time.

but if `<jsp:include page="/jsp/C.jsp" />` you have done this,

then your content of `C.jsp` will come in `A.jsp`(like copy and paste)(at run time only).

after this if you change content of `C.jsp` then you need to again recall refresh of `A.jsp.`